# Ray Marching advantages over Rasterization

Tags: graphics, raycasting

I'd like to know what's reason to use Ray Marching/Ray casting over rasterization? Is it better only in specific cases? 
Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Are you referring to ray casting used for hidden surface removal? Or for actual rendering?

Comment: I mean rendering technique

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ray casting and rasterization are two totally different methods of rendering. Rasterization is designed to be very fast, and lighting is typically computed on a per-fragment basis in a fragment shader (or pixel shader). Ray casting (a type of ray tracing) actually simulates light rays in a sense, creating a more accurate render, with a much larger computation time.

Answer (score 1):

The main advantage of ray tracing(in general) is in the quality of the image.[ray traced image vs rasterized](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fnc9c.jpg). Ray tracing actually simulates a ray of light from the camera through each and every pixel of your screen while also taking into effect natural phenomena like reflection and refraction while computing the final color for the pixel,whereas in rasterization the 3D objects are simple squashed onto the pixels of the screen.